# php with curl to login into website through php code

Tags: php, curl, permissions, file-permissions

I'm getting the execution success message but its not redirecting to the webpage with error:

> `Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /myaccount.php on this server.`

**Code:**

```
$username ='xyz@gmail.com';
$password ='******';
$loginUrl1 ='http://www.zopnow.com/myaccount.php';
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"email=$username&password=$password");
// to ignore all cookies using libcurl
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
$store1= curl_exec($ch);
echo "Executed Successfully with loginUrl1 ".$store1;


curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Does logging in from an actual browser form post work?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is the login URL you are using.

The login form does not submit to the myaccount.php script but to the login.php script.

Try changing

`$loginUrl1 ='http://www.zopnow.com/myaccount.php';`
to
`$loginUrl1 ='http://www.zopnow.com/login.php';`

Also try adding

`&redirect=myaccount.php?&remember=true` to the post fields.

In addition this login page is not encrypted so be cautious about using an account name and password you use else where. If you already have done so, consider changing your password everywhere else you use it.

Comment: i tried , i am not getting that forbidden error , but it will not open with site page

Comment: $loginUrl1 ='http://www.zopnow.com/login.php &redirect=myaccount.php?&remember=true';

Comment: You will probably have to configure curl to store cookies and follow redirects.

Comment: how do i do that , im not trying it on what is exactly required but it not redirecting me nor logging into the website .It just provides me login page